# Placing two regions side by side

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

How to create a page that has two regions placed side by side. I tried creating a parent region and its two child subregions but the two subregions are aligned one above the other even if I specify column size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "right" region should have its "Layout" properties set to:

- start new row = NO
- column = Automatic
- new column = Yes
- column span = Automatic

I suspect you might have set the 1st and the 3rd properties (in the above list) differently, and they do affect the layout.